# Basic server GUI through web browser

Tags: web-browser, php, gui

**Question**

Does there exist a PHP project that allows you to through a website:

1. Browse through a specific directory on a server
2. Upload and download files
3. Run scripts on the server

I want it to be as simple as possible and able to do these three things. I've found many projects that satisfy the first 2 points but not all three.

**More Detail**

I currently am running an Amazon EC2 instance and I would like to display the information in one of the user directories in a GUI style interface through a web browser (i.e. similar to Google Drive).

It needs is to be able to traverse through the directory tree using point and click and can open basic file formats for viewing i.e. .doc, .xls and a number of image formats i.e. .jpg, .png.

Finally it should allow you to be able to upload or delete files and also run scripts e.g Bash or Python scripts.

Does anyone know of any PHP projects that have been written for this purpose?

Comment: `using point and click and can open basic file formats for viewing i.e. .doc, .xls and a number of image formats i.e. .jpg, .png.` - You aren't expecting the server to actually render these .doc, .xls files right?  You are expecting clicking on a file = downloading to the client machine and running the local office application.

Comment: Yes download and run the local office application or opened in Chrome viewer etc. if installed. No server rendering.

Comment: For the most things (not all) you can install any PHP based remote `file-manager`, e.g. `elFinder` or such. But i doubt about bash script executing...